# How to insert rows daily using SSIS so that Identity column will record count of rows?

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package scheduled every day. The theme of package is to copy 1 table data from 100 databases each from server A  to server B. The requirement is databases increases day by day. so, tomorrow total databases are 101 and following day 102. 
The package will truncate all data from 1 tables from 100 databases and will load table with 100 databses and also with new 101 database. Package executing through SQL job is taking ages.

Table has same column structure with Identity RowID column. what I am looking instead of loading every day from starting database I need package to load only new databses i,e 101, 102, 103 and so on. so that Identoty RowID column will record increment.

Is there any possibility to do this. so that will tajke less time.

Thanks.

Comment: will the old databases have the new data or not. or you mean you just want to transfer new databases and ignore the old ones

Comment: Instead of truncating the destination table, why don't you only import the new rows?

Comment: @Tab Alleman , yes I want to insert new rows instead of truncating. please suggest how to do that to load data for only newly coming databases daily

Comment: @Amelia is that possible that news will appear in old databases or just new databases?

Comment: @LONG, no new data to old databases. I need to transfer daily coming new databases table data

Comment: @Amelia then check my answer post below, hope that helps

Comment: How does your package know which databases to import from?   What are you doing to add new databases?   I really can't imagine how you can be adding new databases to a package and not know how to import only from the new database.  Sounds like you've been asked to work on a legacy package that you don't really understand.

Comment: @Tab Alleman , I have table created which gives latest database

Comment: So why can't you use that table to only import from the latest database?

Comment: Yes following @LONG 1. answer I can use the table to get latest data which gived DatabaseName and ImportedDate

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to transfer the newer database and ignore the old ones. Here is the way to do it:

1. Create a new log table for logging purpose. Could have few rows such as `DatabaseName`, `ImportedDate`
2. Create new variable for holding the processed database name
3. Adding `execute sql task` beofre the actual transfer task to check whether the processing database has already existed in that log table, command will look like this:

`if not exists(select DatabaseName from logTable
begin select 1 end)`

and set result to single row

4. Create new variable to map that result in execute sql task
5. Using that result variable in expression constraint to control whether to processed or check another database

Hope this will faster your process

Comment: @Amelia, no problem, update me if you have any further question, I did not detail the answer too much, but that is the main idea for checking and loading in your case. And I assume you are familiar with those tasks well xD